# Complicated MySQL "ORDER BY"

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have some big tables where some values are not correctly added, and it would be too much work rearranging everything. I basically need to sort on "Number" desc, but if Type = 'Food', the Number should be increased by 40%.

```
Name   | Type    | Number
Cheese | Food    | 50
Apple  | Fruit   | 30
Grapes | Berries | 60
```

So in pseudocode:

Select * From Table Order by (if type = 'Food', number = (number * 1.4)), number desc

So the list should be sorted like this:

```
Name   | Type    | Number
Cheese | Food    | 70
Grapes | Berries | 60
Apple  | Fruit   | 30
```

Is this possible?

Comment: "values are not correctly added"... how certain are you that fixing this would be "too much work"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pseudo-code is almost exactly right:

```
Select *
From Table
Order by (case when type = 'Food' then number * 1.4 else number end) desc;
```

I prefer `case` to `if` because it is standard SQL.

Comment: When I try it, it is ordered correctly, however the output number is the same as in the DB.

Comment: @KristianRafteseth . . . I didn't realize you wanted to change the number in the `select` too.  I thought you just wanted the `order by` to change (you would just put the expression in the `select` clause).